# ASP.NET, Streamwriter, Filestream - 0 byte file

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, streamwriter

This works:

```
using (StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("\\xml\\file.xml")))
{
    stw.Write(xmlEncStr);
}
```

This creates an empty file:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("\\xml\\file.xml"), FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        sw.Write(xmlEncStr);
    }
}
```

I tried playing around with the FileStream constructor and tried flushing and I still get a zero byte file.  The string I am writing is a simple base64 encoded ascii string with no special characters.

I know I can use the first example, but why won't the second work?

**Update**

This wasn't a Filestream/StreamWriter problem - it was a variable naming problem.  I corrected the code above, so now both versions work.  I originally had:

```
StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter(file)
```

Comment: The second example is writing to something called 'sw' while the enclosing 'using' block is declaring a 'StreamWriter' called 'strw'.

Comment: Oy vey, Thanks DevMan, I feel pretty stupid right now.

Comment: Steve, for the record, you should edit the question and correct the typo. Or was that mixup the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could shorten your code a bit:

```
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("\\xml\\file.xml"), xmlEncStr);
```

Also the `MapPath` method accepts a relative or virtual path and converts it to the corresponding physical path on the server. `\\xml\\file.xml` is non of the above. It probably should be: `~/xml/file.xml`.

Comment: Dont forget about the actual text to write

Answer (score 1):

#### Not reproducable.

It shouldn't be an ASP.NET issue and the second form ought to work (provided **sw==strw** ).

But `FileMode.CreateNew` will fail if the file already exists, so if you use a fixed filename, and if it was created during an earlier attempt as an empty file then that would explain the symptoms.

But @Darin Dimitrov provides a better alternative.